# Privacy settings with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, privacy

I have friend and privacy module in my application. It has 3 level of privacy: friends, network (friends of friends) and everyone.

Privacy options are

`view_in_search` (who can search a person)

`event_invite` (who can invite a person in events)

What I'm trying to do, is implementing a search. I've written a small algorithm on paper:

1. all basic conditions required
2. check user privacy setting for `view_in_search` key
3. check if user is friend
4. check if user is friend of friend
5. if user privacy is friend condition 3 should be true
6. if user privacy is network either condition 3 or 4 should be true
7. if user privacy is everyone always return true

I want to reduce this 6 conditions is there any way to do it.

`User privacy` is saved in one different table. `Friends` table is different and `Users` table is different.

I'm using Codeigniter and Memcached.

Comment: Check some authentication libraries. I suggest `Ion_auth`. There, you can set different levels of permission by users or by groups. Than just check in constructor of specific controller if sufficient permission level for current session to let visitor to view or redirect to level visitor belongs to.

Comment: it will not work because when I run query for returning user I've to check for each user and current user returning from query

Comment: You lost me. If it is more than authentication matter, you should ask in [right manner](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)